# how to emit and collect an arraylist in storm?

Tags: java, maven, arraylist, apache-storm

I have an arrayList that I want to emit and receive it in another bolt.
So as suggested on another post here I used:
the first bolt:

```
collector.emit(new Values(listI));
```

the next bolt:

```
public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
ArrayList<Integer> i = (ArrayList<Integer>)tuple.getValue(0);
....
}
```

but instead of a size 4 list, I am getting a list with size 0.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what type listI is (I'm assuming an ArrayList). If so, your first bolt might have this:

```
@Override
public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    List<Integer> listI = getSomeListOfIntegers();
    collector.emit(new Values(listI));
}
```

Make sure you also declare it in bolt 1:

```
@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("listI"));
}
```

Then in your second bolt:

```
@Override
public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    List<Integer> listOfInts = (List<Integer>)tuple.getValue(0);
}
```